# Automatically Subscribe to Youtube Channel After it gets a certain amount of subscribers

Tags: python, youtube, subscribe

my question is is it possible to have a Python bot checking every second the subscribers a certain YouTube channel has and after the channel gets a desired amount of subscribers to subscribe us to it?

For example I am looking at channel X that has 1490 subscribers and I want to be exactly the 1500th subscriber. So the code needs to refresh the number every few minutes or seconds.

How do I do that?

I have a basic Python subscriber count code but I am stuck at moving things forward.

If you have any code in any language that can do this automatically I will be forever grateful to you

My current code

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# Create YouTube Object
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3',
                developerKey='Enter API key')

ch_request = youtube.channels().list(
    part='statistics',
    id='Enter Channel ID')

# Channel Information
ch_response = ch_request.execute()

sub = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']
vid = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['videoCount']
views = ch_response['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']

print("Total Subscriber:- ", sub)
print("Total Number of Videos:- ", vid)
print("Total Views:- ", views)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selenium, find the subscribe button in html and then click it. Example of selenium code (for a different website, from the selenium docs):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Get more info at: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

As for running it continuously, just use a loop and break out when the desired sub count is reached.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that you can [only get the three significant figures](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.subscriberCount) of the subscriber count.**

[@Game Developement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16715608/game-developement) shared [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72848758/7123660) that may be quite heavy due to the need of having a web-browser dedicated for this purpose, in addition to be interpreted by YouTube as spam traffic.

I would instead recommend you to use [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) using `part=statistics` to get the subscriber count in `item["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]` and then [Subscriptions: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) to subscribe to the given YouTube channel.

Comment: If YouTube gives you only the three significant figures, does that mean that there is no way for me to see when the channel has 99.999.99 subscribers, so I can be the 100M subscriber?

Comment: Correct, you will just see 99,900,000 subscribers and then 100,000,000.